# How to combine values within a row with comma

Tags: r, rbind

I would like to know, How to combine columns in a dataframe/list in R with a comma separator. Below is the sample dataset.

```
Name Red Blue Green 
Jack 4   5     3
John 5   6     4
Gen  3   7     1
Pra  4   6     2
```

Expected would be:

```
Name Colors
Jack 4,5,3
John 5,6,4
Gen  3,7,1
Pra  4,6,2
```

Immediate help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

We can use `paste` with `do.call`.  Note that even if you have 100 columns to `paste`, the below code does it automatically without having to painfully mention `paste(df1$Red, df1$blue, df1$Green, df1$Orange, etc..., sep=",")` etc.

```
newdf1 <- cbind(df1[1], Colors=do.call(paste, c(df1[-1], sep=",")))
newdf1
#  Name Colors
#1 Jack  4,5,3
#2 John  5,6,4
#3  Gen  3,7,1
#4  Pra  4,6,2
```

Or a similar option with `sprintf`

```
cbind(df1[1], Colors=do.call(sprintf, c(df1[-1], list(fmt="%d,%d,%d"))))
```

---

Or with `unite` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    unite(Colors, Red:Green, sep=",")
#   Name Colors
#1 Jack  4,5,3
#2 John  5,6,4
#3  Gen  3,7,1
#4  Pra  4,6,2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the *paste function* with a "," separator.

```
df$Colors<-paste(df$Red, df$Blue, df$Green, sep =",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `unite` function from the `tidyr` package:

```
tidyr::unite(df_test, Color, -Name, sep = ', ')
```

data:

```
structure(list(Name = c("Jack", "John", "Gen", "Pra"), 
               Red = c(4L, 5L, 3L, 4L),
               Blue = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 6L),
               Green = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L)),
          class = "data.frame", 
          row.names = c(NA, -4L)) -> df_test
```

Answer (score -4):

I would copy the data into excel, add a column with the value , and add a formulae =A1&D1&B1&D1&C1

A,B,C is the columns, D is the comma

Comment: Could you please explain why copying the data to Excel from R in order to do a very basic operation is a good idea? Simply because you don't R perhaps?

Comment: David is right, going to Excel is from R's point of view, a "downgrade". Though this is still a valid answer.